# how to use databinding in fragment

Tags: android, data-binding

I use `DataBinding` in `fragment` ,but there are some trouble
this is the `fragment`

[image]

and this is my layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Try "Clean" and "Make project"

Comment: What is the trouble? Are you get a compilation error? Are you getting a problem with the layout? Is there an exception during execution?

Comment: i cleaned and made project,it works.thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must wrap your layout in a `layout` tag:

```
<layout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

<layout>
```

Also ensure that you enable databinding in your module's build.gradle file:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

And note that you named your binding variable `inflate` but you use `binding.getRoot()` in the return statement. So rename your variable to `binding`. Or change your return statement to `return inflate.getRoot();` Whatever you prefer.

Comment: my layout have the 'layout' tag,just the html not show

Answer (score 2):

Change `binding.getRoot()` to `inflate.getRoot()`